# Asp.net Core env.ContentRootPath gives me Root Folder instead of Project folder

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Both the `env.ContentRootPath` and `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` gives me path:

```
C:\\pathToProjects\\MyProjectRoot
```

But my Project is structured like this

```
├───.vscode
├───docs
├───src
│   └───MyProject
│       ├───project.csproj
├───test
│   └───MyProject.Tests
│       └───project.csproj
└───project.sln
```

Before migration and installation of 1.1.1 version i would get the folder that startup.cs files is in.

One more question if someone could help here.
What is the difference between project.json files project.csproj files and which will be supported in the future and what about sln files how do we update those in vs code.

Comment: The .csproj are going to be supported, not project.json.

Comment: VS Code doesn't use the .sln file and you may not need it in VS 2017 if you choose File > Open > Folder...

Comment: Probably better not to add three extra questions to the end of your post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the `cwd` attribute in the `launch.json` file - it can be used to set the current working directory for finding dependencies and other files.

[Debugging in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Answer (score 1):

There is an official comparison doc on the Microsoft docs site for the differences between project.json and csproj. See - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix paths like this but i dont like it.

HACK:

```
var rootDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\src\\MyProject";

if (hostingEnvironment.IsProduction())
{
    rootDirectory = hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
}
hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath = rootDirectory; //fix for path changes
```